# Closed points of $\text{Proj}(\mathbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Consider $X=\text{Proj}(\mathbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2))$, I want to show that $X(\mathbb R)=\emptyset$.

I have two problems with this. The first one is that I'm not sure of the definition of $X(\mathbb R)$. Is it the set of closed points of $X$ such that $\exists K(x)\hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ an injection ? Do we require that this extension has something more, to be algebraic for example ? Maybe there is a reference I could use.

Since I'm quite sure about the closed points part, we can try to find closed points. Closed points of $X$ are the homogeneous maximal ideals of $\mathbb R[x,y,z]$ containing $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, which is the set $\{(x+y+z)\}$.
We write $x=(x+y+z)$.

My second problem is the computation of $K(x)$.

We get $\mathcal O_{X,x}=T^{-1}(\mathbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2))$ where $T$ is the set of homogenous elements of $R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ not contained in $\overline{(x+y+z)}$. Since I don't get what this thing is I tried to consider the open subset $D(x)$ and compute the stalk on this subset but I'm struggling. Is there a better approach ?

Comment: You’re confused because you’re wrong in the part you’re ‘sure’ about - (x+y+z) obviously does not contain (x^2 + y^2 + z^2).

Comment: Yes, I look stupid now. I was thinking of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ as $(x+y+z)^2$. But then I have even more difficulties seeing what are the closed points.

Comment: It suffices to check affine patches, where your scheme looks like the spec of R[u,v]/u^2 + v^2 + 1. This cannot have any R-points because a sum of squares of real numbers is always..?

Comment: Positive... I thought about using these Spectra even in my wrong case but I can't quite make sense of it.  It should come naturally since in the algebraic closed case we saw $\mathbb P^n$ is a union of affine varieties, and Spec and Proj are the translations in schemes. But it's not clear to me why $X$ is a union of the 3 Spectra.

Comment: You need to revisit the Proj construction. If f is a homogeneous element of S of positive degree then the non-vanishing locus of f in Proj S is simply Spec of the degree 0 part of S_f. Apply this to f = z in your graded ring.

Comment: I revisited the Proj construction but for me it's not necessarily easy to see that $((\mathbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2))_{\bar{z}})_0\cong \mathbb R[u,v]/(u^2+v^2+1)$. Moreover I don't understand your argument, why should I care if $u^2+v^2>0$ or not. What I want to say is that we have that $\mathbb R[u,v]/(u^2+v^2+1)$ is a domain and has a maximal ideal, which is a closed point. Why is it wrong ?

Comment: When did I say there was anything wrong with that? It has lots of maximal ideals. (v) itself is a maximal ideal. None of these maximal ideals correspond to R-points, they all are C-points.

Comment: As for your first question, there is nothing to do except note that a degree 0 element looks like g/z^d, g a homogenous polynomial of degree d in x,y,z. Now just divide each monomial in g by z^d appropriately: Example xyz/z^3 = (x/z)(y/z).

Answer (score 2):

By definition, for any scheme $X$ and any commutative ring $R$,
$$X(R) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(\operatorname{Spec}(R),X).$$
This definition makes sense for schemes in general, although if $X$ is an $R$-scheme you can also take the hom in the category of $R$-schemes, which in some cases can be different. In this problem, $X$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-scheme, but it doesn't matter which interpretation we use: it turns out that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}),X) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}_\mathbb{R}}(\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}),X)$ for any $\mathbb{R}$-scheme $X$. This is something a bit special about the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Anyway, this just means that an element of $X(\mathbb{R})$ (aka an "$\mathbb{R}$-point of $X$") is just a scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}) \to X$. Unwinding definitions, such a morphism is given by a pair $(x,\varphi)$, where $x$ is a point of $X$ and $\varphi : k(x) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism, where $k(x)$ is the residue field of $x$. This is close to what you said, but a bit different: the map $\varphi$ is part of the data of the $\mathbb{R}$-point! The same point $x \in X$ may give rise to many different $\mathbb{R}$-points if there are many different homomorphisms $k(x) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now let's think about the $\mathbb{R}$-scheme structure. Since $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, every ring of local sections of the structure sheaf of $X$ is naturally an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, and thus so are the local rings $\mathcal{O}_x$ and the residue fields $k(x)$ for all points $x \in X$. Now if $(x,\varphi)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-point of $X$, the composite $\mathbb{R} \to k(x) \xrightarrow{\varphi} \mathbb{R}$ must be the identity, because $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial endomorphisms as a field, and therefore $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Moreover, since there are no nontrivial endomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$, whenever $k(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, the isomorphism is unique! Thus, an $\mathbb{R}$-point of $X$ is simply given by a point $x \in X$ such that $k(x) \cong \mathbb{R}$.

Such points are necessarily closed, but this takes a little more working out. It's probably more effective here to just think directly about all of the points of this scheme and work out that none of the residue fields can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. The following lemma might help:

**Lemma** Let $R$ be a commutative graded ring and let $X = \operatorname{Proj}(R)$. Then for each point $\mathfrak{p} \in X$, the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}}$ is isomorphic to the $0$th graded piece of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Comment: So in a more general case we can have that $(x,\phi)$ and $(x,\varphi)$ can be different $K$-points if the morphisms are different ? You also say that the $\mathbb R$ points have to be closed. Is it true in the general case ? That is if we assume that $X(K)$ is the set pairs as you described, then we will see that in fact the points must be closed and so that's why we assumed closed in my definition.

Comment: @raisinsec Right, exactly, if $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are two different maps $k(x) \to \mathbb{R}$ then $(x,\phi)$ and $(x,\varphi)$ give two different elements of $X(\mathbb{R})$. It's not true in full generality that $\mathbb{R}$-points are closed, but it is true that the $\mathbb{R}$-points of a scheme which is locally of finite type over $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the closed points. The proof uses the Nullstellensatz, which is where we need the assumption that $X$ is locally of finite type over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For an example of a non-closed $\mathbb{R}$-point, consider $X=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. An $\mathbb{R}$-point of $X$ is then a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}) \to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, which is the same as a morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$. There is a unique such morphism. So, there should be a unique pair $(x,\varphi)$ as described above. This consists of a point $x \in \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ and a morphism $\varphi : k(x)\to\mathbb{R}$. This forces $x = (0)$ so that $k(x)$ has char. $0$, and indeed there is a unique map $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: ... but $(0)$ is not a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$!

Comment: For an example of a point of a scheme whose residue field admits more than one map to $\mathbb{R}$, consider $X = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))$. Then an $\mathbb{R}$-point of $X$ is a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}) \to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))$, i.e. a morphism $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{R}$. There are exactly two such morphisms: $a + b\sqrt{2}$ can be sent to either $a + b\sqrt{2}$ or $a - b\sqrt{2}$. $X$ has exactly one point as a topological space, so these are two distinct $\mathbb{R}$-points have the same underlying topological point!